# why scala allows return from recoverWith

Tags: scala

I am surprised that scala allows return from `Try.recoverWith`.

Example, following code makes sense because I'm recovering with `Success`

```
scala> import scala.util.{Try,Success}
import scala.util.{Try, Success}

scala> def result: Option[Int] = Try(0/0).recoverWith { case _ => Success(-1) }.toOption
result: Option[Int]

scala> result
res7: Option[Int] = Some(-1)
```

But following code with return does not make any sense at least to me. Which is not even making an effect because toOption still returns `None` not `Some(-1)`

```
scala> def result: Option[Int] = Try(0/0).recoverWith { case _ => return Some(-1) }.toOption
result: Option[Int]

scala> result
res11: Option[Int] = None
```

**Why is the second example even valid code in scala?** because the definition of recoverWith is returning `Try[U]`

```
def recoverWith[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, Try[U]]): Try[U]
```

And if I remove `toOption` part compilation fails which tells there is something between recoverWith and toOption.

```
scala> def f = Try(0/0).recoverWith { case _ => return Some(-1) }
<console>:13: error: method applyOrElse has return statement; needs result type
       def f = Try(0/0).recoverWith { case _ => return Some(-1) }
                                                ^
```

I'm using scala 2.12.3

```
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.3 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

Comment: What version of scala are you using? For me, the second example produces: `Some(-1)` on scala 2.12.4

Comment: I get `Some(-1)` as well in 2.12.5. No clue what recoverWith API stands for.

Comment: Might be related to this issue https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10291 fixed in 2.12.4.

Comment: @XavierGuihot Interesting that the issue you mentioned allows `return None` from collect function. Is it that scala allows returning final-type from anywhere in codebase? Thats insane if true. Whats the point of having function return-type then?

Comment: You always `return` from a named method, `result`. It's a non-local return, i.e. an exception.

Comment: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html

Comment: This lint warning was just proposed, then closed temporarily? https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6515

Comment: @som-snytt interesting. I actually saw the post [Don't Use Return in Scala](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html) long ago never paid attention. Now I understand return is not following the definition of `recoverWith` instead the whole method(like you said `non-local`). Did not expect scala allows breaking the whole flow and returning to the caller.